# Testing a C function with Google Test

Tags: c, embedded, googletest

I'm trying to use Google Test to test some C code but I'm struggling. I don't really understand how to test the code. I've tried something but I don't know if it's OK or not. Can someone explain to me if it's OK what I've done and how could I test the switch part?

This is the Test I wrote:

```
    TEST_F(MPS_Tests, Wai_for_discharging_of_several_rails) {


        MPS__tenPowerUpTrigger enTrigger = MPS__enGetPowerUpTrigger();
        EXPECT_EQ(enPowerUpTriggerFstp, enTrigger);
        MPS__vOnEnterStateAcPu1();
        EXPECT_EQ(MPS__enGetInternalState(enAC), enStateAcPu1);
        EXPECT_EQ(MPS__u16GetSmEvent(enAC), enStateAcPu1);
```

This is the tested code:

```
MPS__tenPowerUpTrigger MPS__enGetPowerUpTrigger(void)
{
    /* TODO: rework after startup trigger is considerd by design */
    return enPowerUpTriggerFstp;
}

/* Wait for discharging of several rails */
void MPS__vOnEnterStateAcPu1(void)
{
    MPS__tenPowerUpTrigger enTrigger = MPS__enGetPowerUpTrigger();
    MPS__vSetInternalState(enAC, enStateAcPu1);

    switch (enTrigger)
    {
    case enPowerUpTriggerFstp:
        MPS__vSetWait(enAC, u16Time_AC1ASU_t4);
        break;
    case enPowerUpTriggerWakeUp:
        MPS__vSetWait(enAC, MPS_TIMER_NOWAIT);
        break;
    case enPowerUpTriggerReset:
        MPS__vSetWait(enAC, u16Time_AC1CSU_t2);
        break;
    default:
        /* error handling */
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to cover all options in the `switch` would be to change `MPS__enGetPowerUpTrigger` to something like this:

```
MPS__tenPowerUpTrigger MPS__enGetPowerUpTrigger(void)
{
    const MPS__tenPowerUpTrigger return_values[3] = { 
      enPowerUpTriggerFstp,
      enPowerUpTriggerWakeUp,
      enPowerUpTriggerReset
    };
    static int idx = 0;

    MPS__tenPowerUpTrigger return_value = return_values[idx];
    idx += 1;
    if (idx >= 3) idx = 0;
    return return_value;
}
```

... and then call `MPS__vOnEnterStateAcPu1` 3 times?